# Django message with breakline and redirect url inside

Tags: django, django-messages

I would like to improve my `django message` with some things : add a `breakline` in the text and add an url using `django reverse url`.

This is my message :

```
messages.error(self.request, _(  f"The link to download the document has expired. Please request it again in our catalogue : {redirect to freepub-home}"
```

I would like to separate my message by adding a new line after the `.` in order to get something like this :

```
messages.error(self.request, _(  f"The link to download the document has expired. 
                                   Please request it again in our catalogue : {redirect to freepub-home}"
```

Then, how I can set django redirection in my message thanks to reverse url to `"freepub-home"` ?

Thank you by advance !

**EDIT :**

I overcome to set breakline :

```
messages.error(self.request, mark_safe(
            "The link to download the document has expired." 
            "<br />"
            "Please request it again in our catalogue : 
            <a href='{% url "freepub-home" %}'> my link </a>")
```

But I don't find up to now how I can pass django url inside because I have an issue with quote and double quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're passing to `mark_safe` is a plain string, it's not interpreted as a Django template, so you cannot use template tags syntax inside it. You have to use the `reverse()` function to get the url and python string formatting syntax to build the message:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

# ...

    # using triple-quoted string makes life easier
    msg = """
        The link to download the document has expired. 
        <br />
        Please request it again in our catalogue : 
        <a href='{url}'> my link </a>
        """
    url = reverse("freepub-home")
    messages.error(self.request, mark_safe(msg.format(url=url)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! It's exactly what I want ;)